# UIScrollView and it's children: why are they placed on top of each other? (AutoLayout)

Tags: ios, uiview, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm making an app where someone can add products to an order. Every product gets it's own UIView and all these products are placed in a UI (and in an array for future references, like a total price, etc). I'm doing nothing too fancy with the adding of the product:

```
/* Create the new product */        
var tmp = Product(data: product)
/* Add it to the scrollView */
scrollView.addSubview(tmp)
```

I am using AutoLayout for the UIScrollView itself, but with no constraints set (I've cleared it as well to check).

To clarify: the Product is a subclass of UIView, just to standardize the look and feel of every individual product.

However, when I add more than 1 product, the new product gets placed on top of the first one instead of below the first one. I have a feeling I'm missing a crucial part of using a UIScrollView with auto layout. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: In the end I solved it by just making a method with (re)calculates the positions since I got the same behavior with the UICollectionView. I was working on the same app in Android and there you can have a child element act like a block (in the CSS sense) element. I was stubborn by looking for the same solution in iOS :)

Comment: Well, Autolayout is similar to the liquid CSS layout sense, although not as flexible and forgiving :P I've included an example of UICollectionView using autolayout in Swift code which doesn't uses frames for each product view.

Comment: Thank you every much Zhang! That's exactly what I was looking for. The constraints were what got me confused. Learned something new today, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIScrollView doesn't automatically position your subview in the correct spot when you call `[scrollView addSubview:productView];`

Before you addSubview to your UIScrollView, you need to tell the subview the correct location using initWithFrame, in this case it appears you're using Autolayout.

If you're open to alternative, I think a UICollectionView achieves what you want. Each "cell" in a collection view is your product view. The collection view has all the functionality that scroll view has.

If you're using frames for your product view, then you might do it like this:

```
var view1:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Notice here, view2 has a Y position that takes the height of view1
//
// So we're telling iOS to put view2 right below view1 before we
// add it as a subview of our scrollView
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
var view2:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, view1.frame.origin.y, 320, 480));

self.scrollView.addSubview(view1);
self.scrollView.addSubview(view2);
```

### UICollectionView Autolayout Demo:

For completeness sake, I'll include a basic UICollectionView Autolayout demo using **Swift**.

### Viewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var arrItems:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();
    var collectionView:UICollectionView?;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.arrItems.addObject("Apple");
        self.arrItems.addObject("Banana");
        self.arrItems.addObject("Orange");
        self.arrItems.addObject("Mango");
        self.arrItems.addObject("Watermelon");

        initViews();
        initConstraints();
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func initViews()
    {
        // ------------------------------------------------------
        // Init the collection View
        // ------------------------------------------------------

        var flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2.0);

        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout);
        self.collectionView?.registerClass(ProductCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID");
        self.collectionView?.delegate = self;
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = self;
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        self.collectionView?.pagingEnabled = true;

        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!);
    }

    func initConstraints()
    {
        self.collectionView?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);

        var views:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary();

        views.setValue(self.collectionView!, forKey: "collectionView");

        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[collectionView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views));
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[collectionView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views));
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return self.arrItems.count;
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // ---------------------------------------------------
        // Note, Swift is able to detect all developer's own
        // class files, so no need to import ProductCell
        // ---------------------------------------------------

        // create a ProductCell
        var cell:ProductCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as ProductCell;

        // setup product info
        cell.productName.text = self.arrItems[indexPath.row] as NSString;
        cell.productDescription.text = "This is some text about the product. It can be a very long block of text or maybe a really short one. Up to you to design it anyway you like.";

        return cell;
    }

}
```

### Product Cell class

```
import UIKit

class ProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var container:UIView = UIView();
    var productName:UILabel = UILabel();
    var productDescription:UILabel = UILabel();

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);

        initViews();
        initConstraints();
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    }

    func initViews()
    {
        self.container.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
        self.container.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

        self.productName.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14);
        self.productName.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        self.productName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
        self.productName.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.productName.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical);
        self.productName.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1.0);
        self.productName.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        self.productName.clipsToBounds = true;

        self.productDescription.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14);
        self.productDescription.numberOfLines = 0;

        self.container.addSubview(self.productName);
        self.container.addSubview(self.productDescription);

        self.contentView.addSubview(self.container);
    }

    func initConstraints()
    {
        self.container.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
        self.productName.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
        self.productDescription.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);

        var views:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary();
        views.setValue(self.container, forKey: "container");
        views.setValue(self.productName, forKey: "productName");
        views.setValue(self.productDescription, forKey: "productDescription");

        // container constraints
        self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[container]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views));
        self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[container]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views));

        // subview constraints

        self.container.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[productName]-10-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views));

        self.container.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[productDescription]-10-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views));

        self.container.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-10-[productName(50)]-10-[productDescription]-10-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views));
    }
}
```

You should end up with something like:

[image: screenshot of UICollectionView Swift demo]

Comment: Hello Zhang, thanks for the reply. So if I understand correctly, if I don't want to explicitly specify the location of the UIView, it's better to use UICollectionView? Funny; I actually wanted to use auto layout to avoid these problems ;)

Comment: I believe UICollectionView was invented for these types of scenarios. You can continue to use frames and use a formula to calculate the position of the product view but autolayout and collection view will give you what you want + handle orientation rotations. If you want, I can provide a demo of UICollectionView above.

Comment: No need! Thanks for giving me a lead which I can follow, I just assumed that a UIScrollView is the 'correct solution' because of it's name and never bothered looking at alternatives. Thank you very much.